# How i can get current location information in google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know the street name or address of user via gps so then i can put radius there for example 100meter or long and show that particular area shops , food places etc ..! Can anyone please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Code to get Location of user

```
  public void getMyLocation(Activity activity) {
    int requestPermissionsCode = 50;
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, requestPermissionsCode);
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (locationListener != null)
            locationListener.onLocationFound(latLng);
        return;
    }


    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, new SingleUpdateListener(), null);


}
```

This Code to get Address from LatLng

```
  public Address getLocationFromLatLng(Context context, LatLng latLng) {
    android.location.Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        return geoCoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1).get(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

you have to register the application on Google API Console 
The code is for Android 6.0
plus pay attation to the listeners..
This is a working code .

Comment: when i will get latitute & longitute .. how i will show only 100 meter radius places that is nearby that lat & lng

Comment: Use the 'Nearby Search Request' [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests], A Places Nearby search is initiated with a call to the PlacesService's nearbySearch() method, which will return an array of PlaceResult objects. Include 'location' and 'radius' to represent the circle's radius in meters.